# Prove the identity $\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{\sinh(x)}$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

> Prove that $$\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{\sinh(x)}$$

I have started with:

$\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\tanh^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{1-\cosh^{-2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=\sqrt{\cosh^2{\frac{x}{2}}-\sinh^2{\frac{x}{2}}-\cosh^{-2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$

I am stuck here.

Comment: Absolutely, nice question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac{\cosh 2x-1}{\sinh 2x} = \frac{e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}} \\
=\frac{(e^x-e^{-x})(e^x-e^{-x})}{(e^x+e^{-x})(e^x-e^{-x})} \\
= \tanh x
$$

Comment: why do $\cosh 2x-1= e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x}$?

Comment: @gbox $\cosh2x-1=(e^{2x}-2+e^{-2x})/2$, but the denominator $2$ simplifies with the same factor from $\sinh2x$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy if you recall the duplication formulas for hyperbolic sine and cosine:
\begin{align}
\cosh2y&=\cosh^2y+\sinh^2y=2\sinh^2y+1\\[6px]
\sinh2y&=2\sinh \cosh y
\end{align}
so, if $x=2y$, you get
$$
\frac{\cosh2y-1}{\sinh2y}=\frac{2\sinh^2y}{2\sinh y\cosh y}
=\frac{\sinh y}{\cosh y}=\tanh y
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{cosh x-1}{sinh x}=\frac{1+2sinh^2\frac{x}{2}-1}{2sinh\frac{x}{2}cosh\frac{x}{2}}$, (by using double angle whereby,$cosh x=1+2sinh^2\frac{x}{2}$)

=$\frac{sinh\frac{x}{2}}{cosh\frac{x}{2}}$

=$tanh\frac{x}{2}$. Hence shown.