# Is there a method to change an integrand as a result of adding a constant within the original integral result?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

For an integral say
$$\int \tanh x dx= \log  \cosh  x \tag1$$
is it possible to add a constant say one specifically to the r.h.s logarithm of (1) giving $\log  (\cosh  x+1)$ with a systematic way of changing the integral on the l.h.s logarithm of (1)?

If not why?

Answer (score 1):

We can obtain $\log(\cosh(x)+1)$ on the RHS by changing the integrand function since $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(\cosh(x)+1)=\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)+1}=\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{\sinh{x}}=\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

This follows from representing the hyperbolic functions as exponentials:

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)+1} 
&=\dfrac{\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}}{\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}+1} \\ 
&=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}+2} \\ 
&=\frac{(e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{-\frac{x}{2}})(e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x}{2}})}{(e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}})(e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}})} \\ &=\frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}-e^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{\frac{x}{2}}} \\ &=\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right). \end{aligned}$

(Alternatively see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565753/prove-the-identity-tanh-left-fracx2-right-frac-coshx-1-sinhx))